# Performance and Tuning with ServiceStack

Tags: web-services, rest, performance, servicestack

I've been doing some testing with ServiceStack, particularly against WCF.  Overall I've been pleased with the performance but encountered during one of my tests a breakdown in performance.  I've been hitting the test ServiceStack based service with a simple WebClient calls returning JSON data from the service.  The test returns a larger set of plain .net objects (~100) resembling an address.

ServiceStack processes the first couple or so dozen in good times when running sets of 100.  However towards the later part of the set times jump considerably.  The obvious is that requests are queuing.  I'm running on a desktop so I'm not expecting stellar performance but I was looking for any suggestions to help speed up ServiceStack.

Comment: You need to profile your app to identify where the bottleneck is, i.e. try comparing that services with one running that just returns the same object models in memory to see if this is a ServiceStack issue or your own code. If it is indeed a ServiceStack issue than submit a stand-alone test-case exhibiting the issue to the mailing group at: http://groups.google.com/group/servicestack